# How to extract an element from a Json Response in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.Net MVC Application and I got a `JSON` response from the server using this code segment.

```
public JsonResult GetVehicleByID(string VehicleID)
{
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;           

    var res = from type in db.Vehicles
              where type.ID == VehicleID
              select new
              {
                  ID = type.ID,
                  RegNo = type.RegNo
              };
    return Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The code above returns the following `Json` (Google Postman)

```
[
  {
    "ID": "000001",
    "Type": "Internal"
  }
]
```

I handled the response using following [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
function GetVehicle(id) {
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: "GetVehicleByID?VehicleID=" + id,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {

            //Parsing Method 1
            //var a = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            //console.log(a.Type);

            //Parsing Method 2
            var b = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(b['Type']);
        }
    });
}
```

I was unable to extract the `Type` element from this response. There are several similar questions in the Stack Overflow & solutions of those questions are about  parsing. I tried to parse in 2 ways but the browser log gives following error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Helping is highly appreciated than flagging this question as duplicate.

Comment: In the debugger mode check with the data..whether it is coming as a object are not

Comment: Yes Guradio. I have tried that also. But same output

Comment: no need to parse because of this `dataType: "json",` try data[0].Type remove the parse

Comment: var a= data.Type ; or data[0].Type.if these two won't works your getting the empty returning value

Comment: You dont need of this line `var b = $.parseJSON(data);`
It would already be json parsed because of this line `dataType: "json"`

Comment: @Chamith check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/2pv1xtgL/)

Comment: @guradio, When i change that line of code to this console.log(data[0]); it prints the whole JSON Response in the log like this 
'Object {ID: "000002", RegNo: "ABB-6781"}'

Comment: @Chamith what exactly are you trying to get?value of `Type`?or the whole  element?

Comment: console.log(data[0].Type);    shows the output as  *undefined*.

@guradio, I want to get the value of Type Element.

Comment: did you c heck the demo?it show internal

Comment: Thank @guradio & Rohit416. Vinoth Narayan.  
console.log(data[0].Type); works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just `console.log(data[0].Type)`. I believe jQuery is already parsing the response as JSON for you because you specified `dataType: "json"` and the response from the server had the right `Content-Type` header.

Comment: It gives an output as 'undefined'

Comment: @Chamith Did you catch my edit? `data[0].Type`? (The response from the server is an array.) Try just `console.log(data[0])` to see what's there.

Comment: @Chamith Then the JSON response from the server likely doesn't actually look like what you have above. What does `console.log(data)` show you?

Answer (score 0):

As @smarx said jQuery already decoded json for you, so you can access directly to the Type from the data variable, but if not, you can parse the json response with the JS function parse:

```
var json_data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(json_data);
```